# Allocate lowest value over n rows to n rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to take the lowest value over n rows and add it to these n rows in a new colomn of the dataframe. For example:
n=3

```
Column 1   Column 2
    5         3
    3         3
    4         3
    7         2
    8         2
    2         2
    5         4 
    4         4
    9         4
    8         2
    2         2
    3         2
    5         2
```

Please take note that if the number of rows is not dividable by n, the last values are incorporated in the last group. So in this example n=4 for the end of the dataframe.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any straight forward way to do this, but here is a working example (not elegant, but working...).

If you do not worry about the number of rows being dividable by *n*, you could use `.groupby()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2,1,5,3,2,5,6,4,1,2] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
n=3
df['new_col']=df.groupby(df.index // n).transform('min')
```

which yields:

```py
    col1  new_col
0      1        1
1      2        1
2      1        1
3      5        2
4      3        2
5      2        2
6      5        4
7      6        4
8      4        4
9      1        1
10     2        1
```

However, we can see that the last 2 rows are grouped together, instead of them being grouped with the 3 previous values in this case.

A way around would be to look at the `.count()` of elements in each group generated by `grouby`, and check the last one:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2,1,5,3,2,5,6,4,1,2] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
n=3
# Temporary dataframe
A = df.groupby(df.index // n).transform('min')
# The min value of each group in a second dataframe
min_df = df.groupby(df.index // n).min()
# The size of the last group
last_batch = df.groupby(df.index // n).count()[-1:]
# if the last size is not equal to n
if last_batch.values[0][0] !=n:
    last_group = last_batch+n
    A[-last_group.values[0][0]:]=min_df[-2:].min()

# Assign the temporary modified dataframe to df
df['new_col'] = A
```

which yields the expected result:

```py
    col1  new_col
0      1        1
1      2        1
2      1        1
3      5        2
4      3        2
5      2        2
6      5        1
7      6        1
8      4        1
9      1        1
10     2        1
```